Neovim and LazyVim: Customising Lualine status line
I am using the LazyVim starter template and I would like the customise the Lualine statusline using the example given here which is:
return {
  -- skip other examples
    {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sections.lualine_x, "")
    end,
  },
 --- more examples follow
}

Except I'd like to put it in its own file ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/lualine.lua and keep the each plugin config override separate. However, placing the example above in the aforementioned file does not change the status line to have that emoji in it. It remains the default.
How can I keep the default LazyVim config options but override just a few options as required?

I came across your question because I was trying to figure out how to display the file type.  I got that working by putting the following into a new file that I named .config/nvim/plugins/lualine.lua.
I also tried your example, and did not get the icon.  So perhaps it's a problem with that particular symbol.
return {
  {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sections.lualine_x, "filetype")
    end,
  },
}

